# some usages of 'for'

Tags: conjunctions

This is a part of the script of the movie 'The Fellowship of the Ring'

NARRATION: Three were given to the elves. Immortal, wisest and fairest of all beings. Seven to the dwarf lords, great miners and craftsmen of the mountain halls. And nine, nine rings were gifted to the race of men. Who above all else, desire power. 
**For** within these rings was bound the strength and will to govern each race. But they were all of them deceived. **For** another ring was made.

...

And the Ring of Power perceived. Its time had now come. It abandoned Gollum. But something happened then that the Ring did not intend, it was picked up by the most unlikely creature imaginable.

BILBO:  What’s this?

NARRATION: A Hobbit. Bilbo Baggins of the Shire.

BILBO: A Ring!

GOLLUM: Lost! My Precious is lost.

NARRATION: **For** the time will soon come when Hobbits will shape the fortunes of all.

I think the 2nd 'for' means 'because' but I'm not sure what the 1st and 3rd ones mean.
Whenever I encounter uncommon 'for', the paraphrase 'because' somewhat somehow seems to make sense but lingering doubts bothers me.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with the previous comment. The clause subordinator "for" is used for _to_ infinitival clauses that have a subject, e.g. _For Ed to lose his temper like that is very unusual_. Elsewhere, it's a preposition with a meaning similar to _because_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instinct about the second one applies to all the uses in that passage. Here's [a discussion of the topic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/for) from the American Heritage Dictionary usage panel:

> Usage Note: *For* has been used as a conjunction meaning "because, since" for over 1,000 years. It is familiar in many famous quotations, from the New Testament's beatitudes (Blessed are the meek: for they shall inherit the earth, Matthew 5:05) to Shakespeare's sonnets (For thy sweet love rememb'red such wealth brings / That then I scorn to change my state with kings). Today this use of for is rare in speech and informal writing, and it often lends a literary tone or note of formality. · Like the word so, *for* can be viewed as either a subordinating or a coordinating conjunction, and it has been treated variously as such. It has the meaning of a subordinating conjunction, since it clearly subordinates the clause that follows it to the previous clause or sentence. But like a coordinating conjunction, *for* has a fixed position in the sentence, and its clause cannot be transposed to precede the superordinate clause containing the main idea. It is ungrammatical in present-day English to say *For they shall inherit the earth: blessed are the meek*. Perhaps because of this ambiguity in function, *for* is treated variously with regard to punctuation. Sometimes it begins a dependent clause and follows a comma, and sometimes it begins an independent clause (as if it were a conjunctive adverb like moreover) and follows a semicolon or period (when it is capitalized as the first word of a new sentence). All treatments are acceptable in standard usage. The difference is really one of emphasis: starting a new sentence with *for* tends to call more attention to the thought that it introduces.

Note that the word lends a certain *gravitas* to the utterance, like turning up the reverb on a microphone, which is why the narration of *The Lord of the Rings* employs it.

Comment: Originally we had only *for*; *because* entered Middle English “thanks” to the Norman Conquest.  Tolkien will have been been more aware of this than many. (Though he’ll of course have also known of its use in the KJV and Shakespeare.)